# Linux display server or program that can route video and/or images between its clients?

Tags: video, images, image-manipulation, video-editing, wayland

The JACK Audio Connection Kit (http://jackaudio.org/) is a really useful tool for working with audio on linux systems. It allows for both audio and MIDI data to be communicated between its clients, keeps them in sync with each other, and does so with minimal latency. This, of course, enables all sorts of separate audio applications to work together, allowing for a very flexible workflow for people who regularly edit/record/stream/create audio..

As with most other things, it's often very difficult to find a single program that fulfills all the needs of your video/image editing/animation workflow. As somebody who spends just as much time with video/images as I do with audio, I've been curious; is there some kind of application/daemon that allows for the routing of video or images from one program to another?

If not, would the development of this type of application be feasible as a Wayland extension? It seems like the way the Wayland protocol works (having each client render its output to a memory buffer that is controlled by the server [i think?]) would create the potential to route the output of one client into another client..

So, does this type of thing exist? And if not, would it be possible in the future in conjunction with Wayland?